# monty hall %50 - %50

Tags: c, random

i am trying to simulate monty hall problem. i didn't realized any problem but i recieve approximately %50 %50 output. i know that there are explanations but i couldnt understand these
please help me

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define win 1
#define lose 0

#define yes 1
#define no 0

int main(){
    //i assume that prize is behind the first door

    srand(time(NULL));
    
    int lose_counter = 0;
    int win_counter = 0;

    for(int i = 1;i <= 10000;i++){
        int game_status;
        int chosen_door = rand() % 3 + 1;
        int choice;

        //first step that i chose a door
        if(chosen_door == 1){
            game_status = win;
        }
        else if(chosen_door == 2){
            game_status = lose;
        }
        else if(chosen_door == 3){
            game_status = lose;
        }
        
        //host says "do you want to change your door"
        choice = rand() % 2;

        if(choice == yes){
            if(chosen_door == 1 ){//this is the case i have chosen 
                                  //first door and change it after question
                game_status = lose;
            }
            
            if(chosen_door == 2 ){
                game_status = win;
            }
            
            if(chosen_door == 3 ){
                game_status = win;
            }
        }

        if(game_status == win){
            win_counter++;
        }
        else if(game_status == lose){
            lose_counter++;
        }
    }

    printf("win: %d\nlose: %d\n",win_counter,lose_counter);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aside: If you intended this to be C++, I would reject it in code review, and point you at the standard [uniform_int](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) and [bernoulli](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/bernoulli_distribution) types

Answer (score 5):

The chances to win when not switching the doors are `1/3`.

If you switch the chances increase to `2/3`.

Your code takes samples of 50% switching and 50% not switching, hence the average of `1/3` and `2/3` comes up as `0.5`.

Answer (score 2):

The odds of winning are 2/3 if you switch.

Using

```c
choice = 1;  // Switch
```

results in win in about 2/3 of your trials as expected.

---

The odds of winning are 1/3 if you don't switch.

Using

```c
choice = 0;  // Keep
```

results in win in about 1/3 of your trials as expected.

---

If you randomly decide to switch or keep, the odds of winning are

( 1/2 * 2/3 ) + ( 1/2 * 1/3 ) = 1/2

Using

```c
choice = rand() % 2;
```

results in win in about 1/2 of your trials as expected.

---

Fixed:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    // I assume that prize is behind the first door

    srand(time(NULL));
  
    unsigned N = 10000;
    unsigned win_if_keep_counter   = 0;
    unsigned win_if_switch_counter = 0;

    for (unsigned i=N; i--; ) {
        int chosen_door = rand() % 3 + 1;
        if (chosen_door == 1) {
            // Monte open door 2 or 3.
            // You win if you keep door 1.
            ++win_if_keep_counter;
        }
        else if (chosen_door == 2) {
            // Monte open door 3.
            // You win if you switch to door 1.
            ++win_if_switch_counter;
        }
        else if (chosen_door == 3) {
            // Monte open door 2.
            // You win if you switch to door 1.
            ++win_if_switch_counter;
        }
    }

    printf("win if keep:   %.1f%%\n", ((double)win_if_keep_counter)/N*100);
    printf("win if switch: %.1f%%\n", ((double)win_if_switch_counter)/N*100);
}
```